# Coordinate-free Definition of Matrix Invariants

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, book-recommendation, exterior-algebra

After reading [this](http://nicf.net/articles/coordinate-free-linear-algebra/) article about the coordinate free definition of trace and determinant I am interested if these ideas can also be applied to other matrix invariants like for example the (coefficients of the) characteristic polynomial or the Jordan normal form. I am mainly looking for book recommendations.

I understand that my question is rather vague, if this question is best asked somewhere else it can be deleted.

Comment: What you are looking for is perhaps what is called [similarity invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_invariance). A complete system of similarity invariants of a square matrix is given by its [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form).

Comment: Sometimes I think it is a great mistake to have matter that can think and feel. It complains so.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, yes this seems to be related to what I am interested in, I will have a look. Can you recommend some books?

Comment: As someone else once commented on this site, the king of coordinate-free linear algebra was Werner Greub, and you might enjoy his books *Linear Algebra* and *Multilinear Algebra*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have any coordinate-free definition of the determinant you're done; you get all the other coefficients of the characteristic polynomial $\det(t - A)$ and these coefficients freely generate all polynomial matrix invariants. One way to prove this is to argue that any polynomial matrix invariant must be a [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) in the eigenvalues, then appeal to the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) to argue that such polynomials are freely generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues, which are exactly the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial.

Alternatively, once you have any coordinate-free definition of the trace, the $k^{th}$ coefficient of the characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^k \text{tr}(\Lambda^k(A))$ where $\Lambda^k$ is the $k^{th}$ [exterior power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Exterior_power). This can be proven by showing that when $A$ is diagonalizable a basis of eigenvectors of $\Lambda^k(A)$ is given by wedge products of $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors from a basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

It is really a crime, incidentally, to discuss the coordinate-free definition of the trace without drawing any pictures. The pictures are called *string diagrams* and they make what's going on here very transparent. You can see them [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/introduction-to-string-diagrams/) and [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/string-diagrams-duality-and-trace/). Here is a teaser, the string diagram proof of the cyclicity of the trace $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$:

[image]